# ASP Net узнать группу ad ldap

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Не могу найти рабочий код для проверки пользователя в ad

этот код не подходит

```
 static bool IsUserMemberOf(string userName, string groupName)
    {
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        using (var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName))
        using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName))
        {
            return userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(groupPrincipal);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, подойдет ли Вам, но получала список групп немного другим способом. Приведу свой код, где получаю список групп, в которые входит пользователь. Здесь не сложно будет добавить строчку проверки на нужную группу.

```
public static System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection GetADUserGroups(string strUser)
{
    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection group = null;
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAP_Path, "MyDomain\AdminName", strLDAP_AdminKey, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    try
    {
        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        object obj = entry.NativeObject;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", strUserIDS);
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if (null == result)
        {
            return null;
        }

        DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

        // получаем список групп пользователя            
        group = user.Properties["memberOf"];            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error. " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return group;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection groups = ADUtils.GetADUserGroups(strADUserAccount);
if (groups != null)
  {
    string groupDn = "Состоит в группах: <br/>";
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
        {
            groupDn += (string)groups[i] + "<br/>";
        }
    lblUserADGroups.Text = groupDn;
  }
```